# If or test condition as modules

Tags: javascript, performance

Take the code below as an example:

```
function foo(b) {
    var words = [ "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet" ];
    var i;

    for(i in words) {
        /a/.test(words[i]); // test 1
        if(b) {
            /b/.test(words[i]); // test 2
        }
        /c/.test(swordstr[i]); // test 3
    }
}
```

Now, sometimes I don't want to execute test 2 on the array `words`, so there is a boolean parameter `b` when I call foo(). But that makes the code test `b` a number of `words.length` times. Of course, an optimization would be as follow:

```
function foo(b) {
    var words = [ "Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet" ];
    var i;

    if(b) {
        for(i in words) {
            /a/.test(words[i]); // test 1
            /b/.test(words[i]); // test 2
            /c/.test(swordstr[i]); // test 3
        }
    } else {    
        for(i in words) {
            /a/.test(words[i]); // test 1
            /b/.test(words[i]); // test 2
            /c/.test(swordstr[i]); // test 3
        }
    }
}
```

But then the code becomes cluttered. Is there a different approach to this situation?

Comment: what happens with the result of `test`? btw, please use not `for ... in` for arrays. a simple `for` loop is sufficient.

Comment: @NinaScholz The 'test`s are a bunch of operations to execute over each element of the array. For example, instead of tests over string, it could an arithmetic operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimization that you describe is called [loop unswitching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unswitching). From what I read, the Java JIT compiler can do this kind of optimization.

I do not know if V8 does this kind of optimizations, too. I would not be surprised but I would also not bet on it. It will also depend on which JavaScript engine you are using.

Side-note: In your example, I do not think it will gain much. It has more advantages if you are iterating over a huge array.

Comment: Yes, it is over a huge array.

Comment: Ok. Maybe the `test(b)` is not that expensive if `word.length` is not too big as well.